# Heroku assets are not loading and seems assets are out of date

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am having an issue where images on my Heroku production site are not being found.  I  have tracked it down to the digest being different in the file system from what it is looking for in the app.  For example, in the logs I see the following errors:

```
app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/nfl_teams/nfcn/chi-6317d0375db3876a5057f2da59bab1dc.jpeg" for 24.55.52.101 at 2016-09-08 23:10:18 +0000

app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/nfl_teams/nfcn/chi-6317d0375db3876a5057f2da59bab1dc.jpeg"):
app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
```

And when I go to the Heroku console and look up the asset using asset_path() I get the following:

```
$ heroku run rails console
Running rails console on ⬢ fbpm... up, run.7463
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.5)
irb(main):001:0> puts helper.asset_path("nfl_teams/nfcn/chi.jpg")
/assets/nfl_teams/nfcn/chi-93d8c8c53ac98c60f7f3fee1fade067dfa9489b24b8fa4bb9fedd4b12da129de.jpg
=> nil
irb(main):002:0>
```

and finally looking at the heroku bash and checking the file in the directory I get:

```
$ heroku run bash
Running bash on ⬢ fbpm... up, run.7321
cd public~ $ cd public/assets/nfl_teams/nfcn
~/public/assets/nfl_teams/nfcn $ ls chi*.jpg
chi-93d8c8c53ac98c60f7f3fee1fade067dfa9489b24b8fa4bb9fedd4b12da129de.jpg
~/public/assets/nfl_teams/nfcn $
```

So, in the console looking at the asset path I get the following file:

**/assets/nfl_teams/nfcn/chi-93d8c8c53ac98c60f7f3fee1fade067dfa9489b24b8fa4bb9fedd4b12da129de.jpg**

And I get the same file when I look in the directory structure.  Yet for some reason the application is looking for this file:

**/assets/nfl_teams/nfcn/chi-6317d0375db3876a5057f2da59bab1dc.jpeg**

Which doesn't exist and throws a routing error.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.4'
#ruby-gemset=Rails_fb

gem 'rails','4.2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'faker', '1.6.3'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'simple_form', '3.1.1'
gem 'cocoon'

#
# Bootstrap support gems
#
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.6.2'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
#gem 'select2-sass-bootstrap-rails'

# The following Gem is used to parse the NFL page for schedules to build
# a season.
gem 'nokogiri'

# Database.  Using the same database for production/development
gem 'pg'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~>3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.7.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.7.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.2'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.5.8'
  gem 'letter_opener_web', '~>1.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.53.0'
  gem 'libnotify', '0.9.1'
end

gem 'uglifier', '2.7.2'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.1.4'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '2.1.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '2.5.3'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.4.1'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.4.1', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

And here is the code I'm using to access the images in my views(I've tried it both with and without the asset_path() call):

```
<%= image_tag(asset_path(team.imagePath), size: "40") %>
```

Can anyone tell me why the app is looking for the wrong file?  Obviously there is some disconnect in the asset pipeline but I can't figure where?

And this problem started after I upgraded from Ruby 2.0.0 to Ruby 2.2.4 which caused me to update a number of my Gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps. In order to force a new precompile of assets on Heroku in Rails 4 you need to do the following:

- rake assets:clobber
- Rake assets:precompile

Then git commit/push to master and push to Heroku and it should do a new precompile that hopefully will sync up the asset pipeline.  **Don't use rake assets:clean as it doesn't force a new compile.**